# show decimal places on client side division

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am populating a template field using the following code

```
<%# ((ListData)Container.DataItem).TotalMinutes / 60.00 %>
```

However, sometimes the returned value shows up like 40.5 or 29 or 34.75.

I would like it to always show the 2 decimal places whether it is 40.50 or 29.00 or 34.75.
The 2 decimal places should always show.

I also tried

```
<%# string.Format("{0:###.##}", (double)((PendingApprovalListData)Container.DataItem).TotalMinutes / 60D)%>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
(((ListData)Container.DataItem).TotalMinutes / 60.00).ToString("N2")
```

[image]

please DO notice it IS ROUNDING !!!

if you want cutiing  :

[image]